# Why does Skype hang randomly when talking with somebody over it?

Tags: xubuntu, skype

From a couple of days I am facing a problem with Skype. When I'm talking with somebody, after 5, 10 or 30 (randomly) minutes it just hangs up. I have this problem with Skype 4.1.0.20 and 2.1.0.81. I'm using Xubuntu 12.10 64-bit.

I've tried to use emulator and run Skype for Windows (3.8), but I can't log in using that.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Please leave a comment telling us what kind of internet connection you are using. Is it a wired connection or is it wifi?

Comment: Wired connection PPPoE